# PHP js Function after onmouse=" throwing error uncaught syntax }

Tags: javascript, php, syntax

here is the code

```
<video title='{$row['title']} {$row['locate']}' 
   class='vidscrollclass' 
   style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; transform: scale(1.0,1.1); z-index:103;' no-controls  
   preload='metadata' 
   ondblclick='
      document.getElementById([$vid]).submit(); 
      return false;' 
   onmouseover='
      document.getElementById([$vid]).addEventListener('touchstart', tapHandler); 
        var tapedTwice = false; 
        function tapHandler(event){
          if(!tapedTwice) { 
             tapedTwice = true; 
             setTimeout( function() { tapedTwice = false; }, 300 ); 
                 return false;
          }
          document.getElementById([$vid]).submit(); 
          return false;
        }'
>
```

For some reason it keeps throwing the same error. iv checked the syntax and everything is in order. The same function works out of php. But in php it throws the error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

If anybody can see what the problem is i would be very thankfull for your input.

Comment: In your`onmouseover` is a single quote after the equals sign. Is this simply a typo? If not, it's going to error at `.addEventListener('`. Use double-quotes to separate the logic.

Comment: That's a mountain of JavaScript to jam into a single attribute. Don't do that. Move that out to a function, as that helps give it room to breathe and avoid conflict on quotes, which is the problem here.

If you quote with `'` you must escape all internal `'` characters or use `"` as an alternative.

Comment: Its in PHP i presumed the quote has to be a ' rather than a " in php

Comment: ok. But i couldnt get the veriable $vid to scope.. but i will try escaping/.

Comment: How do i escape the internal 's - i only know of using a /

Comment: \"touchstart"\ . it worked

Comment: No error now, but its still not functioning just yet...

Comment: even if it worked with escaping the `'` around touchstart: you really should place this js into a seperate function outside of the html and only call the function 'ondblclick'. Setting an eventlistener 'onmouseover' seems even more strange.

Comment: also please show the rendered html (right click-view source) - not the php. My guess is getElementById finds nothing, because you have the `[]` around a maybe string without any `'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo"                                      

            <div style='position:absolute; top:5%; left:{$x}%; width:20%; height:95%; z-index:100;' >


<img src='videobak.png' style='position:absolute; top:-30%; left:-30%; width:170%; height:162%; z-index:101; '>


            <div style='position:absolute; top:5%; left:-15%; width:125%; height:80%; border-style: ridge; 5vw; border-color:{$c}; border-radius: 5vw; background-color:black; overflow:hidden; z-index:102;'>


            <img id='waiter' class='loaderlogo' src='loadinglogo.png' >


                     <video id='$vidd' title='{$row['title']} {$row['locate']}' class='vidscrollclass' style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; transform: scale(1.0,1.1); z-index:103;' no-controls  preload='metadata' onmouseover='tr($vidd , $vid);' ondblclick='document.getElementById([$vid]).submit(); return false;' > 


                     <source src='vid/{$genre}/{$row['videos']}' type='video/mp4' >
                      <source src='vid/{$genre}/{$row['videos']}' type='video/mp4' >
                       <source src='vid/{$genre}/{$row['videos']}' type='video/mp4' >


                       <div style='position:absolute;top:4%; left:4%; width:94%;height:94%;color:white; background-color:red;'><marquee WIDTH=500 HEIGHT=20>---Your browser does not support the video player --Either update your plugins or browser or for best results USE CHROME - CHROMIUM - CHROME CANARY or FIRE FOX BROWSERS for compatibilty assurance---</marquee></div>


                     </video >


        <form id='$vid' action='mainpagesalesvidsphp.php' target='YTiframe' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data';>

        <input id='val1' type='hidden' type='text' name='video' value='{$vid}' >

         <input id='val2' type='hidden' type='text' name='genre' value='{$genre}' >

        <input id='val3' type='hidden' type='text' name='search' value='{$search}' >

        <input type='hidden' type='submit' value='POST'>

        </form>

    </div> 

</div>";
$x=$x+33;

}
$wid=$x; //might need ammending according to math...
?>

<script>

function tr(e , f){
    console.log('yup recieve',e , f)
document.getElementById(e).addEventListener("touchstart", tapHandler); var tapedTwice = false;
  function tapHandler(event) {if(!tapedTwice) {tapedTwice = true;setTimeout( function() { tapedTwice = false; }, 300 );return false;}
  how();

  function how(){
      console.log('sending to',f)
  document.getElementById(f).submit(); return false;} 

  }; 

};
</script>
```

Comment: Who needs json.

Comment: onmouseover='tr($vidd , $vid);'

Comment: function tr(e , f)

Comment: document.getElementById(e).addEventListener

Comment: document.getElementById(f).submit();